# Joomla 2.5 got JAuthentication: :__construct: Could not load authentication libraries

Tags: joomla2.5

I just finished install Joomla 2.5 and then I did log-in at administrator but I got error message

```
 "JAuthentication: :__construct: Could not load authentication libraries."
```

AND home page I got bellow message

```
JERROR_LOADING_MENUS
Error loading component: , 1
Component not found
```

I download "Joomla_2.5.8-Stable-Full_Package.zip" from joomla.org.
So I tried to do

> Find "Extantions" table.
>
> In extantions table, go to page 3 or 4, and find there "plg_authentication_joomla" - enaible it from 0 to 1.

but not work.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 2):

Had this happen to me personally and it turned out to be a bad DB dump.
Fixed by dropping and re importing the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You should go to joomla databases and find the "extensions" table ,you must enable the "plg_authentication_joomla" and "plg_user_joomla" from 0 to 1. After that,it will work!

Answer (score 0):

-------------------- Found Solution -----------------------

1. I back up online website's admistrator folder
2. Install new Joomla on localhost
3. Replace online website's administrator folder with local one
4. Then I can login to website admin panel but some errors appear on front page and website not appears. Screwed up again.
5. Then I re-use online website's administrator folder and surprisingly, my problem solved (I can login to my admin panel and website appearing very well)

> [(Joomla 2.5) JAuthentication: :__construct: Could not load authentication libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103217/joomla-2-5-jauthentication-construct-could-not-load-authentication-librar)

Answer (score 0):

Find "plg_twofactorauth_totp" in the Extension table,  set Enabled from 1 to 0, you can access your Administrator without Authentication. If you want to set Authentication agian, just try! (: