# (Joomla 2.5) JAuthentication: :__construct: Could not load authentication libraries

Tags: php, authentication, joomla

I know it is duplicate of this [JAuthentication: :__construct: Could not load authentication libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376345/joomla-2-5-got-jauthentication-construct-could-not-load-authentication-libr) question but the answer there couldn't help me. What I have done is accidentally disabled Joomla - Authentication plugin in my site's back end. It's been two days I've been trying to solve this problem by browsing on internet. I found most people's problems were solved by enabling plg_authentication_joomla in PhpMyAdmin.

1. Some forums instruct to change permission of tmp,logs,cache and
   administrator/cache to 775 or 777
2. Some forums instruct to enable plg_authentication_joomla and
   plg_user_joomla in PhpMyAdmin
3. Some forums instruct to modify configuration.php and after following their instruction, part of my configuration.php is like below

   `public $log_path = './logs';
   public $tmp_path = './tmp';
   public $cookie_domain = '';
   public $cookie_path = '';`

I would like to know two things

- Why Joomla let disable this kind of plugin if it is the most essential plugin
- How or what should I do to re-gain backend access to my website

If your answer could help my problem, you will be a life saver. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have tried all of above methods and the problem do not solved yet.

UPDATE:

-------------------- Found Solution -----------------------

1. I back up online website's admistrator folder
2. Install new Joomla on `localhost`
3. Replace online website's administrator folder with local one
4. Then I can login to website admin panel but some errors appear on front page and website not appears. Screwed up again.
5. Then I re-use online website's administrator folder and surprisingly, my problem solved (I can login to my admin panel and website appearing very well)

---

But why Joomla let disable this kind of plugin?

Comment: You mean that you changed the enabled status of the plugin from phpmyadmin and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I mean that! But luckily, I found a solution and I updated it in my question. Thank you for you contribution. :)

Comment: `But why Joomla let disable this kind of plugin?` Probably joomla assumes you knew what you were doing. Glad you made it ;)

Comment: Ah, may be! I thought that it was for front end login module and I disable it for faster speed of website. Unfortunately, it was happen. :D